# Ionic and SQLite wait until database info is loaded

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I have a project on Ionic where I need to render some information of the database in the home page, something like a TODO program.

I already have some information on the database and I'm trying to render the list of items but I have the next problem:

- First the home page is loaded without any result
- Then the data from the database is loaded and printed on the screen

The problem is I want the view to wait until the database info is loaded until showing anything, I'm wondering if I can use some kind of loading icon.

I've followed the answer here: [Open database before main controller is called in Ionic and SQlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137406/open-database-before-main-controller-is-called-in-ionic-sqlite-in-ionic-ngcordov)

I have the database initialization working but as I've said, **the data is loaded after the view is rendered**.

I've tried using `$ionicLoading` but I didn't get any good result

This is my view:

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $cordovaSQLite, DB) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
        tasks = []
        var query = "SELECT * FROM task;";

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(DB.db, query, []).then(function(results) {
            if(results.rows.length > 0) {
                for (i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++){
                    console.log("SELECTED -> " + results.rows.item(0).title);    
                    $scope.tasks.push(results.rows.item(i))
                }                    
            } else {                    
                console.log("No results found");
            }
        }, function (err) {
            $scope.tasks = [];
            console.error(err);
        });
        $scope.tasks = tasks;
    });

})
```

This is a video example of the issue I'm having right now:

https://youtu.be/H2fUYQuV3xg

Comment: Have you tried resolve in routes ?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Maybe you can use resolve in your routes , to call a service where you can fetch data from database .. as it will execute first before entering into view .. Maybe it will solve problem (Y) Just a guess . didnt try it myself

Comment: Mmmm that sounds nice, If I can fetch the data before entering the view that would be perfect. I will look on the docs for that, Thanks !

Comment: yeah .I think so too .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution following the advice of using resolve in my routes.

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl',
    resolve: {
        tasks: function(DB) {
                return DB.getTasks();
                    });
        }
    }
})
```

I have a factory called DB where I have some functions to retrieve data from the database. On this example I load the tasks before entering on the URL using `DB.getTasks()`

To load the variable **tasks** resolved on the route I have to add the variable name on the function like this:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function (tasks) {

    $scope.tasks = tasks;
})
```